# Librería threading Python3

Tags: python-3.x, hilos

tengo una pequeña duda con respecto a la librería threading de python3, estoy aprendiendo recién como utilizar esa lib, y veo que la gente cuando hace uso de ella hace esto, un ejemplo:

```
def worker():
   print("inicio")
   time.sleep(2)
   print("fin.")

threads = []

for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

Lo que no entiendo es por qué se crea la lista threads, y para que nos serviría, ya que encontré otro script que hace lo mismo pero en ningún momento hace uso de esa lista, solo añade los hilos a la lista.

Comment: No es necesario crear la lista, ahí solo se almacenan los hilos y si l9s quieres ver solo accedes a la lista, no hay otro truco

Comment: Entiendo, pero para que me serviría la lista?

Comment: como dije, para alancearlo, después puedes ir a la lista y ver los hilos que se han ejecutado, nada mas. Solo para tener *un registro*

Comment: osea un registro de los hilos que se han ejecutado o como

Comment: exacto!, una vez el hilo termina de ejecutarse ya no sabes nada de este

Comment: muchas veces, en vez de añadirlos a una lista solo se hace un `print(thread)` para que puedas ver cual proceso se está ejecutando

Comment: @Christian la pregunta es válida para una respuesta, puedes responderla a partir de tus comentarios, explicando con detalle la razón. No es necesaria mucha redacción para esta respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Bien!, ahí lo puse ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu lista `thread` almacenas cada hilo creado, cada hilo es independiente de otro y ejecuta su tarea en paralelo, en este caso la tarea que le pasas es invocar la función `worker()` pero recién lo inicias cuando haces `thread.start()` el método `start()` esto invoca al método `run()` del hilo.

Una vez se ha invocado el método `start()` el hilo se considera *vivo* y podemos decir que *muere* cuando la ejecución de su tarea finaliza ya sea completando su trabajo o generando una excepción no controlada. Al haber terminado ya no queda nada de este, por lo que no podrás usarlo, pero si puedes *verificarlo* (si esta vivo o no) con el método `is_alive()`. Tu lista sirve como una especie de registro donde se almacena cada thread creado durante el `for` (no el thread en si, creo que se almacenaba una instancia de este) también puedes guardar su nombre usando el atributo `name`. He visto varios ejemplos donde en vez de usar una lista, simplemente se imprime el hilo haciendo uso de un `print(thread)`

Otra forma de guardarlos, es usando su atributo `name` para así saber su nombre y tener los hilos un poco *más ordenados*.

```
#... resto del código

for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(thread.name) #guardamos su nombre
    #print(thread) #tambien podemos imprimirlo
    thread.start()
```

Si quieres saber más puedes leer la [documentación del modulo threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)